# Cannot sort results in sql by more than 1 column after using CASE

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sorting

previously, my SQL code, which looks like this, worked perfectly (it selects all the rows that fit the criteria, and then first sorts by column_5, or rather the fifth field, and then column_6)

```
SELECT *
FROM   table
WHERE column_2="blah" AND column_4=34
ORDER BY column_5,column_6
```

But then, I wanted specific results to be on top, so I used the CASE command, but when I do it I can no longer sort the rest of the results by more than 1 column. For example, the following code will work:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table
WHERE column_2="blah" AND column_4=34
ORDER BY CASE WHEN column_3= 'blah' THEN '1'
              ELSE column_4 end
```

But this does NOT work =>

```
SELECT *
FROM   table
WHERE column_2="blah" AND column_4=34
ORDER BY CASE WHEN column_3= 'blah' THEN '1'
              ELSE column_4, column_2 end
```

I'm getting a syntax error near the comma around `column_2`.
It's like I can't sort by multiple columns after I do the CASE command. Does anyone how what I'm doing wrong and how I could fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM  your_table
ORDER BY CASE WHEN column_3 = 'blah' 
              THEN 1
              ELSE 2
         END,
         column_4, 
         column_2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM  table
WHERE column_2 = 'blah' AND column_4 = 34
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN column_3 = 'blah'
    THEN column_5
    ELSE column_6
    END,
    column_4, column_2
;
```